# Load balance TCP with HAProxy

Tags: tcp, haproxy, syslog-ng

I want to set load balancer for syslog-ng messages, so let say several boxes are sending TCP 514 messages to fronend interface of HAProxy box - 192.168.0.20 and there is one graylog server to which those messages are passed - 10.0.0.2.

Below simplest possible config doesn't work.

defaults
        mode tcp

frontend main
        bind 192.168.0.20:514
        use_backend graylog

backend graylog
        server graylog1 10.0.0.2:514

Tcpdump is showing that HAProxy is sending RST flag to incoming messages on 514. I believe I should see HAProxy listening on 514 with netstat?

Answer (score 0):

RST for SYN packet means the port is not open for connection. Use netstat utility to determine if the ports are open. RST can also be sent when the entity wants to close the established connection for good.

Comment: Thanks you right, this is what I meant by writing "I believe I should see HAProxy listening on 514 with netstat?". I don't see HAproxy listening on 514 (or any other port), so this is purpose of this post. Not sure why haproxy doesn't open any of the ports (tried also with http, smtp).

Comment: Question isn't answered, rather want to know how to set up TCP load balancing on HAProxy. But thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a config that should work. You have to be root (or sudo) to bind to port 514 though.

```
defaults
    mode tcp
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms

listen graylog
    bind *:514
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    server graylog1 10.0.0.1:514
    server graylog2 10.0.0.1:514
    timeout connect 20s
    timeout server 30s
```